# use of gerund form in an imperative sentence

Tags: clauses

X traveled in a bus. He found no seat. He had to stand all the journey. How would this be described best ?

**I. He traveled in a bus standing.**

**II. He traveled in a bus while standing.**

**III. He stood in the bus while traveling.**

Similarly, which one is more natural out of the following three, if we are instructing someone that they should be seated when they're drinking water:

> A. Drink water while sitting.
>
> B. Be seated while drinking water.
>
> C. Drink water being seated.

Answer (score 1):

Both II and III are grammatical and idiomatic. III is preferable stylistically because the initial verb indicates what is noteworthy.

Similarly, A and B are both grammatical, but B, by starting with the action desired as the imperative verb, strikes me as more effective and more natural.

By the way, I do not view any of the participles in these examples as gerunds. They are not acting as nouns, but rather as modifiers. And in your second set of examples, I'd prefer "when" to "while" because drinking water is a very brief process compared to traveling, but this perhaps is a purely personal idiosyncrasy.